# Can't get Compass to watch my Susy project

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass, susy-sass

I am a newb to the command line. The furthest I have taken it was to install the sass version of Foundation successfully. I want to try out Susy to see if it suites my needs better. I was following the 11 videos series on Susy Tutorials on Level Up Tuts by Scott Tolinski. I followed him step by step during the installation process all the way up until the "compass watch" command within my root folder. I was then thrown this error:

```
NoMethodError on line ["31"] of /Users/bradgabel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-1.0.0.rc.0/lib/compass/sass_compiler.rb: undefined method `on_compilation_starting' for #Sass::Plugin::Compiler:0x007fe4a41def80>
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

The gems I have installed are:

- compass (1.0.0.rc.0, 0.12.7)
- compass-core (1.0.0.rc.0)
- compass-import-once (1.0.4)
- sass (3.4.0.rc.2, 3.2.19)
- susy (2.1.3)

Comment: So, what was the output with the --trace option?

Comment: This appears to be a new issue specific to 1.0.0.rc.0, you can check the progress on it here:  https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1736.  In the mean time, you might try downgrading to Compass 1.0.0.alpha.21.

Comment: Ok sorry cimmanon. Thank you I'll give it a try

Answer (score -1):

Try to put this on your sass file.

```
@import "susyone";
```

hope can solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I am also having issues using compass watch from the command line but mine was after I updated my susy / sass gems. I have found that using preros was much easier and you can configure it to use the same config.rb file + your system ruby gems without having to navigate the command line. Best of luck.